# want to go to home page when clicked on back button in mobile?

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am developing a mobile app on ionic framework. It has a side menu with subcategories. Whenever I go to the subcategory more than once and click on the back button in android mobile, it retraces whole of the states it went through which I don't want.

```
.state('eventmenu', {
  url: "/event",
  abstract: true,
  templateUrl: "templates/event-menu.html"
})



.state('eventmenu.home', {
  url: "/home",
  views: {
    'menuContent' :{
      templateUrl: "templates/home.html",
      controller: "HomeCtrl"
    }
  }
})


.state('categorymenu', {
  url: "/category",
  abstract: true,
  templateUrl: "templates/event-menu.html"
})

.state('categorymenu.compound', {
  url: "/compound",
  views: {
    'menuContent' :{
      templateUrl: "templates/categories.html",
      controller: "CategoriesCtrl"
    }
  }
})

.state('categorymenu.research', {
  url: "/research",
  views: {
    'menuContent' :{
      templateUrl: "templates/categories.html",
      controller: "CategoriesCtrl"
    }
  }
})



.state('categorymenu.product', {
  url: "/product",
  views: {
    'menuContent' :{
      templateUrl: "templates/product.html",
      controller: "CategoriesCtrl"
    }
  }
})


$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/event/home");
})
```

I want the back button to redirect user to the home page. Here **categorymenu.compound** and **categorymenu.research** are the contents of sidemenu, which has got many subcategories that would redirect to **categorymenu.product** page.

Answer (score 0):

redefine backbutton function on each controller loading, you can use :`$ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function(){$state.go('targetView')}, priority, [actionId])`

but you need clear cache when you reload views (for redefine backbutton each time and have SEVERAL possible return).

you can add param in each redirect :

```
$state.go('targetView',{cache: false});
```

or add param in state description

```
.state('eventmenu.home', {
  cache: false
  url: "/home",
  views: {
    'menuContent' :{
      templateUrl: "templates/home.html",
      controller: "HomeCtrl"
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the reply..this solution isn't working. But i think this would just redirect me to home page. Is there a better possible solution where i could delete the unwanted states from the history stack of ionic. I read about $ionicHistory.clearHistory, but I am not sure how to proceed with it.